# CocoaPod - The `public_header_files` pattern did not match any file

Tags: cocoapods

I am storing a pre-compiled framework in Amazon s3.  "pod spec lint" fails with following errors.

```
- ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.
- ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `public_header_files` pattern did not match any file.
```

Running it with verbose option shows that it is downloading from s3, but instead of copying the downloaded framework, Cocoapod is copying the framework from '~//Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/' directory. This turns out to be empty framework.  Because of this, "pod spec lint" fails with the above mentioned errors.

Here is the relevant part from "pod spec lint" output

> Http download
>   $ /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o
>   /var/folders/qv/ld8pxb7d0_s1xn1mztqktj8h0000gn/T/d20160601-3868-fmxlyy/file.tgz
>   https://s3.amazonaws.com/framework.ios.sdk/MyFramework.framework.1.0.tar.gz
>   --create-dirs --netrc
>
> ```
>  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left   Speed
> ```
>
> > 100 67562  100 67562    0     0  74480      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 74407
>
> $ /usr/bin/tar xfz /var/folders/qv/ld8pxb7d0_s1xn1mztqktj8h0000gn/T/d20160601-3868-fmxlyy/file.tgz
>   -C    /var/folders/qv/ld8pxb7d0_s1xn1mztqktj8h0000gn/T/d20160601-3868-fmxlyy
>   Copying MyFramework from
>   `/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/MyFramework/01a6da9f1381e3dbc8db63de5409d451-2eea2`
>   to
>   `../../../../private/var/folders/qv/ld8pxb7d0_s1xn1mztqktj8h0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/MyFramework`
>
> Running pre install hooks

When I manually copied the framework to '~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External' directory validation goes through.

Here is the podspec file.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

s.name             = 'MyFramework'
s.version          = '1.0'
s.summary          = 'MyFramework'

s.description      =  'MyFramework'
s.source           = { "http"=> "https://s3.amazonaws.com/framework.ios.sdk/MyFramework.1.0.tar.gz"}
# s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/<TWITTER_USERNAME>'

s.platform     = :ios, "8.0"
s.source_files = 'MyFramework/Classes/**/*','MyFramework.framework/Headers/*.h'
s.ios.public_header_files =  'MyFramework.framework/Headers/*.h'
s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'MyFramework.framework'
s.ios.frameworks = 'CoreGraphics', 'Foundation', 'MobileCoreServices', 'Security', 'SystemConfiguration', 'UIKit'


s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
s.dependency 'Mantle', '~>2.0.4'
s.dependency 'AWSCore'
s.dependency 'AWSS3'

end
```

Is there anything that I am missing in the podspec file.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your `source_files` property must contain project's source files, like

```
s.source_files = 'MyFramework/Classes/**/*.{h,m,c}'
```

And your `public_header_files` must refer to your headers in the project, not in the result framework, like

```
s.ios.public_header_files =  'MyFramework/Classes/PublicHeaders/*.h'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's relevant, but running `pod cache clean --all` helped me.